# Child component causing too many renderings on parent component when changing global state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React web application, I have a global state for storing some data, for some reason I happen to see quite unnecessarily renderings on my app!

I have component that looks like this:

```
const LanguageSkills = () => {
  const [languageSelected, setLanguage] = React.useState({})
  const { dispatch } = useContext(GlobalStore)

  const handleChange = (name: string) => (event: any) => {
    setLanguage({ ...languageSelected, [name]: event.target.checked })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: ApplicantActions.FILTER_APPLICANTS,
      payload: {
        languageSkills: languageSelected,
      },
    })
  }, [dispatch, languageSelected])

  return (
    <>
      {
          {languageSkills.map((lang, index) => (
            <TermWrapper key={index}>
              <GreenCheckbox onChange={handleChange(lang.term)} value="checked" />
              <Term>{lang.term}</Term>
            </TermWrapper>
          ))}
      }
  </>
  )
}
```

This component causes the parent component to render without any action doing from this component, well because the dispatch function is called immediately inside **useEffect()** once the component gets mounted (at least what I know), how else can I handle this so dispatch only gets called when I click the radio button? Is there any callback or someway that I can call dispatch once the local state changed using **setState()**?

Any idea how can I use dispatch in such situations?

Answer (score 1):

Update this line

```
<GreenCheckbox onChange={handleChange(lang.term)} value="checked" />
```

to this

```
<GreenCheckbox onChange={() => handleChange(lang.term)} value="checked" />
```

you are calling the function in render time. give it a callback

UPDATED:

```
const handleChange = (name: string) => (event: any) => {
    setLanguage({ ...languageSelected, [name]: event.target.checked })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    callMe();
  }, [languageSelected])

 const callMe = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: ApplicantActions.FILTER_APPLICANTS,
      payload: {
        languageSkills: languageSelected,
      },
    })
 }
```

Comment: still this does not reduce number of re-renderings, but good point thou! I just think I dont need useEffect in this case but where do I put dispatch once i update language!

Comment: Why cant do in the same function 'handleChange'?

Comment: doesnt work calling dispatch function after setState() the dispatch doesnt get the newest state this way

Comment: forgot it, try pass only 'languageSelected' into the useeffect. updated answer

Comment: it will still call callMe once the component is mount, which is undesired behavior for me, i only want the dispatch to be called once the input change

Comment: I came up with some solution, and seems like working!

Answer (score 0):

After several trying I came up with this and it seems fine for me, does not cause anymore parent component to re-render!

```
const LanguageSkills = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({})
  const { dispatch } = useContext(GlobalStore)

  const handleChange = (name: string) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const obj = { ...state, [name]: event.target.checked }
    dispatchLanguageFilter(obj)
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked })
  }

  const dispatchLanguageFilter = useCallback(
    obj => {
      const languageSkills: string[] = []
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (value) {
          languageSkills.push(key)
        }
      }
      dispatch({
        type: ApplicantActions.FILTER_APPLICANTS,
        payload: {
          languageSkills: languageSkills,
        },
      })
    },
    [dispatch],
  )

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper onClick={() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)}>
        <FilterContainerTitle>Kielitaito</FilterContainerTitle>
        <Arrow>{!isVisible ? <ArrowDown /> : <ArrowUp />}</Arrow>
      </Wrapper>
      {isVisible && (
        <>
          {languageSkills.map((lang, index) => (
            <TermWrapper key={index}>
              <GreenCheckbox onChange={handleChange(lang.term)} value="checked" />
              <Term>{lang.term}</Term>
              <TotalAmountWrapper>
                <TotalAmount>{lang.totalAmount}</TotalAmount>
              </TotalAmountWrapper>
            </TermWrapper>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Not sure if its right way but mission accomplished!